# Any plans to burninate [project-planning]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The tag [project-planning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-planning) has 212 questions at the time of writing this proposal.

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

It's ambiguous. It can mean a lot of things depending on the context. It can mean structuring your code, files inside your C++ project, managing employees working on the project, project cost estimation, etc.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

No, the tag excerpt clearly states that it's off-topic.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No. Better use other tags that describe the language or technology.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No. In programming it could mean a lot of things. In non-programming context in can mean something completely different.

Comment: When are we going to stop this farce of claiming it satisfies the burn criteria, for every tag we want to burn?

Comment: If it's off-topic, shouldn't most of the hundred or so (as of now) [open questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bproject-planning%5D+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ano&searchOn=3) with this tag be closed?  Then we could be talking about, say, ten actual questions and whether this tag helps them.  As is, it is frequently the correct tag for the question even as the question is wrong for the site.  Perhaps some of the better questions should be migrated.  Closing doesn't require burnination.

Comment: @mdf isn't this exactly what burnination is?

Comment: More than half the questions with that tag (109 out of 211) are closed.

Comment: @mdfst13 Prior to this request being posted, anyone could have felt free to vote to close the hundred or so questions.   It is likely, however, that without the wider visibility of the burnination process, that those close votes would age out after 4 days and nothing would change.  Burnination enables exactly what you are asking for, in a means that encourages more people to look specifically at questions with that tag and close them.

Comment: @DonaldDuck that estimate suffers from survivor bias.  There are likely many more closed-and-deleted questions.  Would be awesome if someone wrote a SEDE query to identify the tags with the highest percentage of closed+deleted questions which would be likely burnination candidates....